# reinitialize the variable to dice rolled value to glow the path in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am creating a ludo game, I want to glow the path  when the dice rolled, I am writing this is Mouse_OVER event, at first time path is glowing from starting position according to dice rolled value, and i will move pawn to some position, in the second time of dice roll when Mouse_OVER path is again glowing from starting position because it is reinitializing againg to 0, but i want glow the path from where the pawn is to dice rolled value.

please help me. thank you.

```
 opawn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hovero1);
 function hovero1(event:MouseEvent): void{
 var filterarray: Array=new Array();
for(var i=0;i<die1+1;i++)
{
    s1[i].filters=[glow];
    glow.alpha=2;
    glow.color=0xffd700;
    glow.inner=true;
    filterarray.visible=true;

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it glow from the latest path, you must store that value in a variable and re-initialize from that path. In your code I am not sure which is the path variable I am assuming it must be s1[i].

So suppose on the first roll you are moving four places from 0 (i.e.) 0,1,2,3 then on the next roll your die comes up with a value of say 2 (i.e.) from 3 till 5 then your glow path variable must start from s1[3] and apply the glow filters to s1[4] and s1[5].

In your code the s1 variable will always be from zero and this variable must be moved elsewhere that will track the last move made along with the current moves to be made